# How can I change the name of a lwc that is part of a flexipage using the setup?

Tags: lightning-web-components, flexipages

I have a flexipage that contains many components.  I need to change the name of one of the components.  How can I do that manually using setup?   Or is there a different way to do it manually?  By manually I mean not using Intellij.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems we don't have any edit options for LWC from setup. You need to go through VSCode/ any other IDE to rename it and push it back to respective org.

Comment: Thanks.  My issue is that I have changes that are being deployed to 2 orgs at the same time.  One of them is a temporary testing org that needs to use the new component, that's why I wanted to change the component name manually.  The other org shouldn't use the new component.   The testing org is being used for changes that won't be deployed until next year for a large project.

Comment: Your best bet is to copy code and create same comp  with new name.